# angular 9 - async best practises?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, design-patterns, rxjs, angular-ivy

After upgrading from 8 to 9 async logic in html doesn't work anymore.

like this

`<div id="app" *ngIf="(applicationsList$ | async) as applicationsList">
    <app-search-filter [(applicationsList)]="applicationsList"></app-search-filter>
</div>`

Out of this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34405
and on the Ivy guide 
https://next.angular.io/guide/ivy-compatibility.

It throws now an errorr if you use it.

> ERROR in Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "applicationsList". Template variables are read-only.

*Im of the opinion that this is not an antipattern, cause you can easily handle Change detection with it.*

**My question now :**

What is the best practice(elegant way) to replace this kind of code to remove the error?

I know there is the possibility to use promise instead but is it really the best way?:

.ts

```
this.applicationsList = await this.applicationApi.getList().toPromise();
```

.html

```
<div id="app">
  <app-search-filter [(applicationsList)]="applicationsList"></app-search-filter>
</div>
```

EDIT :

Here is a Stackblitz with the error if you see in the dev console :

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-taatzh

Comment: The pattern itself doesn't look incorrect. Can you reproduce the problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: Try this, subscribe to the async call in code behind. Put debugger statement in subscription. Comment out html code. Put in new div nothing in it. Restart navigation then tell us what happens after pressing f12 to debug. You should see the breakpoint hit. What values do you see?

Comment: Also, as mentioned in that GitHub issue, `[(applicationsList)]="applicationsList"` is the probable source of the error, not the use of the `async` pipe.

Comment: I have upgraded the stackblitz in the GitHub issue comments to Angular v9, and the usage of the pattern itself is OK. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-issue-34405-ppcbhy A live demo of the issue would benefit the question.

Comment: @KurtHamilton your stackblitz has the version 8 .  I updated my answer with the error

Comment: Why the banana in a box here? What do you expect to happen with the implicit event you are creating?

Comment: I followed the approach of changdetection like https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/ .Even without the Bannana in a box the reason that causees the problem is the *ngIf="(applicationsList$ | async) as applicationsList"

Comment: what is in the app-search-filter?

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit weird to pass a template variable into an output, but if you want simply you a hack with an object.

```html
<div id="app" *ngIf="{list: applicationsList$ | async} as data">
    <app-search-filter [(applicationsList)]="data.list"></app-search-filter>
</div>
```

I would write a separate handler and update template to

```html
<div id="app" *ngIf="(applicationsList$ | async) as applicationsList">
  <app-search-filter [applicationsList]="applicationsList" (applicationsList)="update($event)"></app-search-filter>
</div>
```